# Help understanding predicate logic question/proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me? I can't even understand what the question is asking for.

> Let $S = \{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\}$. Show that ${\sim}[\forall x\in S,P(x)\lor Q(x)]\iff \exists x\in S,[{\sim}P(x)\land {\sim}Q(x)]$

Comment: Hi Melvin. Welcome to MSE. If you want to ask a well-received question, you should format your question in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather then posting an image. See also [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking you to use known logical equivalences (an incomplete list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)) to get from the first statement to the second. In fact, this can be done with just two known equivalences:

\begin{align}
\sim[\forall x \in S, P(x) \vee Q(x)] &\iff \exists x\in S,[\sim(P(x)\vee Q(x))] \tag{Negation of $\forall$}\\
&\iff \exists x\in S,[\sim P(x) \wedge \sim Q(x)] \tag{DeMorgan's Laws}
\end{align}

Comment: thx, i also think tis way before, but i quite confuse because of the question is actually 6 marks, can i juz write tis simple way to get the marks or it actually got other more complicated way to solve it

Comment: In principle, the instructor might expect you to "expand" the universal quantifier $$\sim [\forall x \in S, P(x) \vee Q(x)] \iff \sim [(P(x_1) \vee Q(x_1)) \wedge (P(x_2) \vee Q(x_2)) \wedge \cdots \wedge(P(x_n) \vee Q(x_n))],$$ but I'm not sure why they'd want you to do this as it doesn't generalize to an infinite set $S$.

Comment: oic... thx everyone, i think i kno how to solve ald